# Contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[MSTransaction]' contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed column, it should be persisted.

This is the error that I am receiving. Any solutions? Here is the SQL code for both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MSOrderline] 
(
    [PurchaseID] NCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [ProductID]  NCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]   INT         NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [DoubleMS_PK] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PurchaseID] ASC, [ProductID] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([PurchaseID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSTransaction] ([PurchaseID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([ProductID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSProducts] ([ProductID])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MSTransaction] 
(
    [TransactionID] NCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID]    NCHAR (200) NULL,
    [CustomerID]    NCHAR (200) NULL,
    [PurchaseID]    NCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [Amount]        INT         NULL,
    [TotalAmount]   INT         NULL,
    [TimeOfSale]    NCHAR (200) NULL,
    [DiscountID]    NCHAR (200) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TransactionID] ASC),

    FOREIGN KEY ([DiscountID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSDiscount] ([DiscountID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSEmployee] ([EmployeeID]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSCustomer] ([CustomerID])
);
```

I know this has been asked before, but it either didn't work in my situation or I couldn't work it into my situation.

Comment: Long character fields are such a bad idea for primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Linoff said, these `NCHAR(200)` are a horrible choice for clustering keys.

You have to create the table to be referenced first. To use `PurchaseId` as a key, it must be `unique`.

example in sql server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MSTransaction] (
    [TransactionID] NCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID]    NCHAR (200) NULL,
    [CustomerID]    NCHAR (200) NULL,
    [PurchaseID]    NCHAR (200) NOT NULL unique,
    [Amount]        INT         NULL,
    [TotalAmount]   INT         NULL,
    [TimeOfSale]    NCHAR (200) NULL,
    [DiscountID]    NCHAR (200) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TransactionID] ASC)
    --,FOREIGN KEY ([DiscountID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSDiscount] ([DiscountID]),
    --FOREIGN KEY ([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSEmployee] ([EmployeeID]),
    --FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSCustomer] ([CustomerID])
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MSOrderline] (
    [PurchaseID] NCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [ProductID]  NCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity]   INT         NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [DoubleMS_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PurchaseID] ASC, [ProductID] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([PurchaseID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSTransaction] ([PurchaseId]),
    --FOREIGN KEY ([ProductID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[MSProducts] ([ProductID])
);
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZVZD33282

Reference for making better choices on clustering keys:

- [Ever-increasing clustering key – the Clustered Index Debate……….again! - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/)
- [The Clustered Index Debate Continues… - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)
- [More considerations for the clustering key – the clustered index debate continues! - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/more-considerations-for-the-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-continues/)
- [How much does that key cost? (plus sp_helpindex9) - Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/how-much-does-that-key-cost-plus-sp_helpindex9/)
- [Disk space is cheap, that is not the point - Kimberly Tripp](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/)
- [101 Things I Wish You Knew About Sql Server - Thomas LaRock](http://thomaslarock.com/2015/06/101-things-i-wish-you-knew-about-sql-server/)
- [SQL Server: Natural Key Verses Surrogate Key - Database Journal - Gregory A. Larsen](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3922066/SQL-Server-Natural-Key-Verses-Surrogate-Key.htm)
- [Ten Common Database Design Mistakes - Simple Talk - Louis Davidson](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/ten-common-database-design-mistakes/)